# getting phone book to application

Tags: android, database, contacts, android-contentresolver

I wrote the following code to get the contact details.  The problem is the phone number I am getting is showing null.  Can You help me?

```
private void displayRecords() {
    // An array specifying which columns to return.

    String columns[] = new String[] { People.NAME, People.NUMBER_KEY};
    Uri mContacts = People.CONTENT_URI;
    Cursor cur = managedQuery(mContacts, columns, // Which columns to return
            null, // WHERE clause; which rows to return(all rows)
            null, // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
            null // Order-by clause (ascending by name)

    );
    if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
        String name = null;
        String phoneNo = null ;
        do {
            // Get the field values
            name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NAME));
            phoneNo =cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(People.NUMBER_KEY));
            Toast.makeText(this, name + " " + phoneNo, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } while (cur.moveToNext());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try People.NUMBER instead of NUMBER_KEY

Answer (score 1):

try this code it will helpful for u

```
  people = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        int position=0;
        Cursor q=db.query(mProfile,new String[]{"person_name"},"person_name"+"!='"+null+"'",null,null, null, null);
        people.moveToFirst();
            int nameFieldColumnIndex = people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);    
            while(!people.isAfterLast()) {
                Cursor o=db.query(mProfile,new String[]{"person_name"},"person_name"+"='"+people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex)+"'",null,null, null, null);
                if(!(o.getCount()>0))
                {  
                mConname.add(position, people.getString(nameFieldColumnIndex));
                try{
                    String contactId = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String hasPhone = people.getString(people.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));
                    if ( hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
                        hasPhone = "true";
                    else
                        hasPhone = "false" ;
                    if (Boolean.parseBoolean(hasPhone)) 
                    {
                        Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ contactId,null, null);
                        while (phones.moveToNext()) 
                        {
                            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                            mConno.add(position,phoneNumber);

                        }
                        phones.close(); 
                    }   
                    if(hasPhone=="false")
                    {   mConname.remove(position);
                    }   
                    else
                        position++;
                }       
                catch(Exception e)
                { 

                }
            }
                people.moveToNext();
            }
```